# PHP filemtime time zoned

Tags: php, html

PHP coding question

How do I add DateTimeZone ('America/NewYork') to the PHP code at the end? I need my code to use filemtime. I included this footer.html in my main files so that all my website pages have the same footer. I also need the footer to filemtime the current file and not just header.html. If you know how to fix that too, please help me out.

```
<footer>

<div style="padding:0 30px">

<p>Validated by:</p>

<a href="https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img src="https://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml11"

alt="Valid XHTML 1.1" height="31" width="88"></a>

<a href="https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer"><img

src="https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss-blue" alt="Valid CSS"></a>

<p>Last modified:

<?php echo " ".date("F j Y g:i a.", filemtime("header.html")); ?>

</p>

</div>

</footer>
```

I tried rewritting the whole thing but nothing worked. As in nothing showing up at all or the time is 0:0.0

Answer (score 2):

What you want, if I understand you correctly is to output the timestamp of `filemtime("header.html")` in the timezone of `America/NewYork`.

This is how you would do that:

```php
$timestamp = filemtime("header.html");

$date_time = new DateTime();
$date_time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
$date_time->setTimestamp($timestamp);

echo $date_time->format("F j Y g:i a.");
```

Note that it is `America/New_York` and not `America/NewYork`.

If you want to display the `filemtime` of the current file you can use [`__FILE__`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php):

```php
$timestamp = filemtime(__FILE__);
```

Comment: The code in my original post is  footer.html; when I go to code my webpage, instead of having to type the footer for every page I make, I use <footer><?php include "footer.html";?></footer>     
I need to keep the valid things.

Answer (score 0):

[filemtime()](https://php.net/filemtime) produces a Unix time, which is not subject to time zones (it's a fixed moment in time). All PHP functions that operate on Unix time and require a time zone (e.g. [date()](https://php.net/date)) read it from the global value. Such value can be set with the [`date.timezone` directive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) or the [date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function.